# Problem when adding \cite{} command within custom 2 argument new command

Tags: macros, citing

I am trying to use a defined command to replace text in a new file version, while also keeping old text.

```
\newcommand{\replace}[2]{ \textcolor{red}{\sout{#1}} \textcolor{blue}{#2} }
```

The command takes two arguments, the first is the old text which will be shown in red and strikethrough, the second argument will show new text in blue.

It works fine until I try to add a citation inside the command, i.e:

```
\replace{old text \cite{citation}}{new text}
```

I receive the following error:

```
ERROR: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. ...text \cite{citation}}{new text}
ERROR: Missing } inserted. ...text \cite{citation}}{new text}
```

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: \sout is quite picky regarding its argument, normally only simple text works well. You can try to put the \cite in a \mbox.

Comment: Perfect. This solves the problem. Thanks a lot..!